# Iterate through xml tree with unknown structure and size (for xml to registry)

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Thanks in advance.  I have an xmldocument of unknown structure and dissimilar elements.  I want to iterate through all elements getting the element name and it's value ultimately to rebuild the xml document into registry keys and values

example

```
<Root>
  <Names>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Names>
  <Locations>
    <States>
      <State>Ohio</State>
      <State>Michigan</State>
      <State>
        Florida
        <WeatherType>Hot</WeatherType>
      </State>
    </States>
  </Locations>
</Root>
```

the output would include the xpath (which I would use for the reg path) for each element value (which i will use for the reg key value).  Output would look something like this.

```
Root\Names\Name = Bob
Root\Locations\States\State = Ohio
Root\Locations\States\State = Michigan
Root\Locations\States\State = Florida
Root\Locations\States\State\Florida\WeatherType = Hot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you're looking for isn't xpath. Ex. the xpath for the `WeatherType`-node is `Root/Locations/States/State[contains(text(),'Florida')]/WeatherType`.

To get what you're asking for, I would approach it like this:

1. Find all nodes with text-value
2. Get path for parent nodes

   - Add text-value to path when siblings of same type (element-name) exists, ex. States.
3. Output `path = text-value`

Ex:

```
#$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path myfile.xml)
$xml = [xml]@"
<Root>
  <Names>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Names>
  <Locations>
    <States>
      <State>Ohio</State>
      <State>Michigan</State>
      <State>
        Florida
        <WeatherType>Hot</WeatherType>
      </State>
    </States>
  </Locations>
</Root>
"@

#Get nodes with text-value
$nodesWithText = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[text()]")

foreach($node in $nodesWithText) {
    #Start with end of path (element-name of the node with text-value)
    $path = $node.LocalName
    #Get parentnode
    $parentnode = $node.ParentNode

    #Loop until document-node (parent of root-node)
    while($parentnode.LocalName -ne '#document') {

        #If sibling with same LocalName (element-name) exists
        if(@($parentnode.ParentNode.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.LocalName -eq $parentnode.LocalName }).Count -gt 1){
            #Add text-value to path
            $path = "{0}\$path" -f ($parentnode.'#text').Trim()
        }

        #Add LocalName (element-name) for parent to path
        $path = "$($parentnode.LocalName)\$path"

        #Go to next parent node
        $parentnode = $parentnode.ParentNode
    }

    #Output "path = text-value"
    "$path = $(($node.'#text').Trim())"
}
```

Output:

```
Root\Names\Name = Bob
Root\Locations\States\State = Ohio
Root\Locations\States\State = Michigan
Root\Locations\States\State = Florida
Root\Locations\States\State\Florida\WeatherType = Hot
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant.  Clean and simple.  I thought I would have to have a function which would keep calling itself for each element, this is even better.  Thank you very much for taking the time to answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Personally I would wrap it in a function to convert each node to path so it would be reusable. Then keep only the "select text nodes" and foreach-loop in the script. But that's just my personal preference so I kept it out. Only 4 lines of code to change it anyways.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight modification to "Frode F"'s code:

```
function Get-XMLTree($xml) {
    $nodesWithText = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[text()]")
    foreach($node in $nodesWithText)
    {    
        #Start with end of path (element-name of the node with text-value)
        $path = $node.LocalName

        #Get parentnode
        $parentnode = $node.ParentNode

        #Loop until document-node (parent of root-node)
        while($parentnode.LocalName -ne '#document')
        {
            #If sibling with same LocalName (element-name) exists
            if(@($parentnode.ParentNode.ChildNodes | Where-Object { $_.LocalName -eq $parentnode.LocalName }).Count -gt 1)
            {
                #Add text-value to path
                if($parentnode.'#text')
                {
                    $path = "{0}\$path" -f ($parentnode.'#text').Trim()
                }
            }

            #Add LocalName (element-name) for parent to path
            $path = "$($parentnode.LocalName)\$path"

            #Go to next parent node
            $parentnode = $parentnode.ParentNode
        }

        $count += 1
        
        #Output "path = text-value"
        "$path = $(($node.'#text').Trim())"
    }
}
```

This takes into account an error condition I ran into while using the above code.